# Miktex and Texmaker on MacOs12.2

Tags: miktex, texmaker, mac

I have installed MikTex followed by texmaker on my mac. Somehow texmaker is not able to detect the presence of miktex. It keep on throughing one or another error like this -

**Could not start the command.
"pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex**

**Log File not found !**

I tried to changed path for commands -- texmaker->preference->command like -

**"/usr/local/bin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex**

but still no help.

I saw that it was mention in Miktex site that sometime we need to change path in terminal, i tried that too. But I am not good at all with command line or terminal operations. So not sure if I did it correct or not.

I am using Miktex with different editors for more than a decade but always on windows machine. This is my first installation on mac.

Any help here. Thanks, Hss

Comment: I don't use a mac or miktex but does it really install into usr/local/bin?  is tex in your path ie can you type `pdflatex --version` at the terminal? if so you should not need a path in editor setting

Comment: I'd think that most latex editors on mac assume mactex (which sets up a very special path to use). Btw mactex is probably _the_ easiest latex dist to install.